Graphing an arbitrary function off of another arbitrary function as the axis. How to scale based off of arc length.
I have created a Desmos Project that lets you graph an arbitrary function g(t), off of a different arbitrary function f(t) as the axis. Really the functions are plotting g(x) and f(x) I just wrote the variable as t since Desmos plots them the same and I use a parametric function to plot the final output.
To use the grapher you only have to choose f(t), and g(t).
Here's how it works: It adjusts the x-coordinates x(t) and y-coordinates y(t) using something akin to polar coordinates. In essence g(t)cos(angle) gets the x-value of the output and g(t)sin(angle) gets the y-value of the output.
Adjusting the x-coordinate has three cases based on the sign of the derivative of the axis function f(t).
If the derivative is less than 0 it sets the x-coordinate as x(t) = $t + g(t)cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\left|\arctan\left(\frac{d}{dt}\left(f\left(t\right)\right)\right)\right|$, if the derivative is equal to 0 it sets the x-coordinate as x(t) = t, if the derivative is greater than 0 it sets the x-coordinate as x(t) = $t - g(t)cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\left|\arctan\left(\frac{d}{dt}\left(f\left(t\right)\right)\right)\right|$.
The y-coordinate has only one case, it sets y(t) =  $f\left(t\right)+g\left(t\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\left|\arctan\left(\frac{d}{dt}\left(f\left(t\right)\right)\right)\right|\right)$.
The reason the angle inside cosine or sine is $\frac{\pi}{2}-\left|\arctan\left(\frac{d}{dt}\left(f\left(t\right)\right)\right)\right|$ is because this gets the angle perpendicular to the tangent line to the curve axis f(t).
This works fine, but currently it takes an input value t based off of the distance along the x-axis, basically if you plug in t=1, you start at x = 1 on the x-axis and go up or down to the axis function f(t) at x = 1, and then plot off of the point (t,f(t)).
What I want to do is find when the arc-length along f(t) is 1 in terms of x, and plot with whatever that value is rather than x = 1 to get the output. Call the arc length L, I want to plot off of the point (L(1), f(L(1))) rather than (1, f(1)).
I know that the arc length formula is L = $\(\int_{0}^{t} \sqrt{1 + \frac{d^2f(x)}{dx^2}} \,dx\)$, but it seems that I need to solve for t in terms of L.
Wolfram alpha can solve this numerically if I enter a specific value of L and a specific function f(t), but I would like to get this working automatically in desmos, for an arbitary f(L). Do I have to turn to scripting and or numerical methods, or can it be scaled to the arc-length along f(t) with a workaround that doesn't use the arc-length formula which may in some cases not even have a closed form solution?
